# How to make dataset, where there last variables will be in one column

Tags: sas

I have a dataset:

```
1  300  apple   pear     onion
1  302  banana  tomato   cookie
2  302  bread   meat     tomato
```

How to make dataset, where there last variables will be in one column.
What I need:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGm3e.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the `CATX` function (or its siblings, `CATS`, `CATT`, `CATQ`, `CAT`).

```
new_var = catx(var1,var2,var3)
```

Or a couple of other options:

```
new_var = catx(of var:); 
new_var = catx(of var1-var3);
```

If they're all starting with the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use `proc transpose` with your categories in the `by` statement and the variables to transpose in the `var` statement:

```
data have;
input var1 var2 var3 $ var4 $ var5 $;
datalines;
1  300  apple   pear     onion
1  302  banana  tomato   cookie
2  302  bread   meat     tomato
;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want (drop=_name_ rename=(col1 = fruit));
by var1 var2;
var var3 var4 var5;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't concretized.  I need to do it in proc report.( Maby with split).
Name of my variables. are: number  name  first  second  third. I need dataset, where will be columns number name xxx(first second third in one column)